# Dropdown element match width of elements inside

Tags: html

The dropdown has two elements with one image in each. Both images are the same size.

I want to match the width of an list item to the image inside.

[image: current version]

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Resources/united-kingdom.png" OnClick="ChangeLanguage_English" Height="30px" Width="30px" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Resources/germany.png" OnClick="ChangeLanguage_German" Height="30px" Width="30px"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the display property of `ul` and/ or `li` accordingly;

```
ul li {
   display: inline-block; /* or display: table; */
}
```